# RESTCONF/Yangdata endpoints not working properly with URL encoding

Tags: rest, http, curl, encoding, ietf-restconf

Lets take this URL for example

```
https://<ip>/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/interface/GigabitEthernet=1
```

If i send a request to a similar endpoint using the internal library we've been using the server doesn't understand it since the = is encoded to %3D but making the same request on the CLI with curl works fine.

I'm not understanding why it's an issue, isn't = supposed to be encoded in a URL anyway? Is it something to do with the library treating it as a query?

Answer (score 0):

The `=` represents a special character with special meaning in a RESTCONF URI. If you encode it as `%3D`, you take that special meaning away and reduce it to just a character. The only case where you would do that is when a list's key value or a leaf-list's value contain this character and you are referencing such an instance in your URI.

You are only allowed to use `=` when referencing list and leaf-list instances - and you do not percent encode it when you do use it.

In your case, `GigabitEthernet` would be expected to represent a list/leaf-list, with its key/type accepting `1` as a valid value. Both `native` and `interface` would be (and can only be) containers (or anydata).

[RFC8040, Section 3.5.3, Encoding Data Resource Identifiers in the Request URI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8040#section-3.5.3) describes this in detail.

Here are the examples from the same section:

> Examples:
>
> ```
>  container top {
>      list list1 {
>          key "key1 key2 key3";
>           ...
>           list list2 {
>               key "key4 key5";
>               ...
>               leaf X { type string; }
>           }
>       }
>       leaf-list Y {
>         type uint32;
>       }
>   }
> ```
>
> For the above YANG definition, the container "top" is defined in the
> "example-top" YANG module, and a target resource URI for leaf "X"
> would be encoded as follows:
>
> ```
>   /restconf/data/example-top:top/list1=key1,key2,key3/list2=key4,key5/X
> ```
>
> For the above YANG definition, a target resource URI for
> leaf-list "Y" would be encoded as follows:
>
> ```
>   /restconf/data/example-top:top/Y=instance-value
> ```
>
> The following example shows how reserved characters are
> percent-encoded within a key value.  The value of "key1" contains
> a comma, single-quote, double-quote, colon, double-quote, space,
> and forward slash (,'":" /).  Note that double-quote is not a
> reserved character and does not need to be percent-encoded.  The
> value of "key2" is the empty string, and the value of "key3" is the
> string "foo".
>
> Example URL:
>
> ```
>  /restconf/data/example-top:top/list1=%2C%27"%3A"%20%2F,,foo
> ```

Note the last example in particular. You would need to percent encode a `=`, if it appears after `list1=` in its key value.

Note that also that these are not parts of a query - they are path segments (RFC3986 terms).